# Gradle error in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, gradle

I have change gradle manually but this error didn't gone.

> Error:Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.0\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1-all.zip.lck

Comment: change `4.1` to `4.4`

Comment: android studio and gradle is 3.0

Comment: wrapper-properties to 4.4 check ..it

Comment: delete gradle and restart android studio. it will download latest gradle from internet.